# Can (neo)WISE detect the coolest Y-dwarfs?

Tags: space-telescope, brown-dwarf

The [WISE telescope](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/WISE/main/index.html) discovered some Y brown dwarfs already. Is the neoWISE mission able to detect even the coolest ones (such as Y9 dwarfs) within five light-years distance? If so, the telescope would have discovered all of them already, right?